# Executable jar file won't run after doing some updates

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am working on Java project (A terraria like sandbox game) and I have come across something that I just don't understand.  I have been exporting the project as .jar's as I go along to upload and share with my friends, but the last time I did this, the .jar won't run, but when I run it in eclipse, it runs fine.  When I try to run the jar all it does is lose focus on the explorer window for a split second, then goes back.  I have tried many things, like changing the main class, changing the META, and moving the files to specific packages, but nothing is working.

The project is 9 classes, so I won't paste all the code for it here, but the latest, non-working source code can be found here (http://www.mediafire.com/?fiw6wq73j7cff4t), the non-working jar here (http://www.mediafire.com/?bhjo162oh3hi2j9), and the working jar here (http://www.mediafire.com/?h918s8xpyxw4psr).  If someone with more experience in java could please take a look at this it would be much appreciated.

One of the things I tried was not adding the JPanel (the game), and just leaving the splash screen, and the jar worked.  This shows that it must be a problem in the coding somewhere.

Thanks for the time,
I.D.

Comment: any exception it throws?

Comment: The only thing is that when I try to run it through the console it says "Couldn't find"

Comment: 1) You seriously expect people to download & examine 100+ Kb of RAR to help you?  I for one don't have that much time.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) *..it says "Couldn't find"*  Couldn't find what?  An end to that sentence?  Please copy/paste output.

Comment: 1) Sorry, just seeing if anyone find problems in the layout or anything  2) That is all it says.... "Couldn't find"  nothing after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Couldn't find` message comes from your `ReadMap` class. So check which circumstance leads to this error. Most likely you did not add all classes or other files to your JAR, so file is not found. Check that all needed files are added to exported JAR in Eclipse export dialog. It's also a good idea to provide more debugging info (stacktrace is ok), especially when you are studying. BTW, cool game :)

Comment: I stopped using the ReadMap class because I made the map randomly generating, I'll try getting rid of the class (not permanently deleting it, just moving it for now) and seeing if that helps.  Thanks for the help and complement on the game!

Comment: Update: IT WORKED!! I just moved the ReadMap class and Map1.txt out of the project and now the .jar works perfectly, thanks you so much for that!

Comment: Congrats! Don't forget to include more debugging info in your future works.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, there just wasn't much I could find, seeing as it ran perfectly in eclipse, just not as a .jar